# Explorer (11) font include doesn't work

Tags: css, fonts, explorer

I really don't know what is the problem with my css, but the font doesn't work in ie. I tried everything what I found here or on the net. Somebody have any idea? (My eot font is converted from otf.)
Here is my css:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'glober-bold';
    src: url('glober-bold.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), 
         url('glober-bold.ttf')  format('truetype'),
    }

body{font-family:"glober-bold", sans-serif;}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try more formats like this (include WOFF):

```
@font-face {
                font-family: 'BankGothicMdBTMedium';
                src: url('style/bankgthd-webfont.eot');
                src: local('BankGothic Md BT'), local('BankGothicBTMedium'), url('style/bankgthd-webfont.woff') format('woff'), url('style/bankgthd-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'), url('style/bankgthd-webfont.svg#webfontNgZtDOtM') format('svg');
                font-weight: normal;
                font-style: normal;
            }
HTML, BODY {
                font-family: BankGothicMdBTMedium, tahoma, lucida, courier;
                font-size: 18px;
            }
```

Comment: @Zellerfisch by this page http://caniuse.com/#feat=woff the WOFF should really be supported in IE 11

Comment: I'm sorry, you are right! I made a little mistake... Thanks you!